# SignalR C# client error: FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

**Edit:**
This error seems to happen only on my mac. My friend used my client and server code on his Windows 10, same Unity3D version and it works. Any ideas what could be causing this error?

I have a C# client and server using SignalR. The server is running fine but the client always throws `FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format` when running `StartAsync()`.

Here is my code:

```cs
// Client.cs
private void Awake() {
    _Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/GameHub")
    .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
        logging.AddConsole();
    })
    .Build();
}

// called when a button is pressed in Unity
public async void OnClickStartConnection() {
    await _Connection.StartAsync();
}
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddInternal (System.String name, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] values, System.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderInfo headerInfo, System.Boolean ignoreInvalid) (at <efff4cb93af94c0c950db61b78368b54>:0)
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add (System.String name, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] values) (at <efff4cb93af94c0c950db61b78368b54>:0)
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add (System.String name, System.String value) (at <efff4cb93af94c0c950db61b78368b54>:0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.CreateHttpClient () (at <fc48509a267447ccb7af409e5c632056>:0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.set_RemoteEndPoint (System.Net.EndPoint value) (at <fc48509a267447ccb7af409e5c632056>:0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory+<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext () (at <fc48509a267447ccb7af409e5c632056>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection+<StartAsyncCore>d__58.MoveNext () (at <ed36b975686d4d58873fbe97ee97567d>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection+<StartAsyncInner>d__50.MoveNext () (at <ed36b975686d4d58873fbe97ee97567d>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult () (at <ed36b975686d4d58873fbe97ee97567d>:0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection+<StartAsync>d__49.MoveNext () (at <ed36b975686d4d58873fbe97ee97567d>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
Client+<OnClickStartConnection>d__2.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Client.cs:31)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:153)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks() (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:107)
```

The issue doesn't even reach the server, from what I can tell. Looking at the stack trace it errors when adding a header to HttpHeaders. How can I fix this?

Environment:

- Mac OS High Sierra
- AspNetCore.SignalR 5.0.7, installed with NuGet for Unity
- Unity3D 2020.3.11f
- Vs Code IDE

Comment: Unity uses `.Net Framework 4.X` .. not sure but I think the issue might be related to `SignalR` beloning to `AspNetCore`

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit more? You mean I can't use SignalR with .Net Framework 4.x, but why?

Comment: I using signalR 7.0.0 with same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: @amirhoseinadlfar Were you able to find a solution? Same problem here

Comment: @AllenRufolo no i switched to gRPC

Comment: @amirhoseinadlfar Solved it this morning by switching build backend from Mono to IL2CPP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same issue as https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30137

The Mono library has issues with headers and I'm guessing you're using Mono in Unity. You could try working around the issue by targeting netstandard, or you could try referencing a newer version of the SignalR client since this was fixed in 6.0.0-preview3.

Comment: I was using Mono, I changed it to IL2CPP, no change. Also changed from .Net 4.x to netstandard 2.0 but no change as well. I did quit and restart Unity, just in case that would make a difference, but no matter what I change there, the issue is the same. I tried to download version 6.0.0-preview3 but it doesn't even appear for download on NuGet for Unity and when I tried to manually download the dlls before it wouldn't install correctly so I'm unsure of what to do now.

Comment: I was having a similar issue but building with IL2CPP solved the problem for me. If anyone else is having this issue it's worth a shot.